# Spring boot jdbc data repository by multi data source

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data, datasource

please help me.
I use multi data source in my project

data source properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=db
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
spring.datasource2.username=xxxx
spring.datasource2.password=xxx
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories(
    jdbcOperationsRef = "mysqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations",
    basePackages = "com.example.demo.mysqlModels"
)
public class Config extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

   @Bean("mysqlDataSource")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource2")
   public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create()
               .build();
   }

   @Bean(name = "mysqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations")
   NamedParameterJdbcOperations mysqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource mysqlDataSource) {
       return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(mysqlDataSource);
   }}


@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories(
     jdbcOperationsRef = "mssqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations",
    basePackages = "com.example.demo.mssqlModels"
  )
  public class Config2 extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

   @Bean("mssqlDataSource")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
   public DataSource mssqlDataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .build();
   }

   @Bean(name = "mssqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations")
   NamedParameterJdbcOperations mssqlNamedParameterJdbcOperations(@Qualifier("mssqlDataSource") DataSource mssqlDataSource) {
       return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(mssqlDataSource);
   }}
```

repository in com.example.demo.mssqlModels:

```
public interface MssqlRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {}
```

repository in com.example.demo.mysqlModels:

```
public interface MysqlRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {}
```

my service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MyService {
   @Autowired
   private final MssqlRepository mssqlRepository;
   @Autowired
   private final MysqlRepository mysqlRepository;
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       log.info("mssql result {}", mssqlRepository.findAll());
       log.info("mysql result {}", mysqlRepository.findAll());
  }}
```

but result is same and both repositories read data from mysql datasource

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking at my question I raised recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546277/spring-jdbc-repository-with-2-datasources-uses-incorrect-datasource-for-one-of-t) regarding 2 data sources but each applied to a different repository.

1. In your configuration classes you should also create two TransactionManagers with unique names.
2. In each repository annotate it with `@Transactional(transactionManager = 'transaction manager name')` replacing the transaction name with the appropriate name
3. You'll probably need to override the default methods such as `saveAll()` with the same annotation as in (2).

However as per my question I found that an incorrect data source is sometimes used (I've since found that having the Postgres classes as the primary resolved my problem but I don't know why this worked)